# Can I get both MAX and COUNT from a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Please take a look at [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/252ac5/3). I have an `author` table, and a `book` table, you know how that works:

```
create table author (
  id int auto_increment,
  first_name varchar(50),
  last_name varchar(50),
  birthdate date,
  death date null,
  birthplace varchar(50),
  number_of_children int,
  mother_name varchar(100),
  other_meaningless_stuff text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table book (
  id int auto_increment,
  author_id int,
  title varchar(100),
  release_date date,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

In plain English, I want to obtain **all the fields in `author`**, the number of books released after the author's death, and the last book released after his death. In MySQL, I could:

```
select author.*,
  (select count(*) from book where book.author_id=author.id and book.release_date > author.death) post_mortem_books,
  (select max(release_date) from book where book.author_id=author.id and book.release_date > author.death) last_post_mortem_book
from author;
```

As you can see, both subqueries have exactly the same `WHERE` clause - but that seems a waste, since both table are very large. Another solution is to `GROUP BY` every field in the query, but that can be vwey slow. How can I get that result in a more optmized way?

Comment: You could create a `VIEW` that contains the posthumous books, then join on the `VIEW`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with a nested subquery in the `select` clause.  So, switch the query to use a `join` and `group by`:

```
select a.*,
       sum(case when b.release_date > a.death then 1 else 0 end) as post_mortem_books,
       max(case when b.release_date > a.death then release_date end) as last_post_mortem_book
from author a left outer join
     books b
     on a.author_id = b.author_id
group by a.author_id
```

Comment: Thanks. How fast will that `group by` be with a really big database?

Comment: @AugustoMen . . . It depends what you mean by a really big database.  For a few thousands or tens of thousands of rows, it should be fine.  For millions, your approach with the appropriate indexes is probably faster in MySQL.

Comment: This solution explores an 'issue' in MySQL, that not all selected fields must be in the `group by` expression. But as it fits, I'm going with this one.

Comment: @AugustoMen . . . Actually, this use of "hidden columns" is compatible with the ANSI standard, assuming that `author.author_id` is declared as unique (or a primary key).  Most databases don't support this standard feature; MySQL happens to but also supports more general (and in my opinion sloppier) constructs.